# List and patterns

Tags: list-manipulation

Given some tuple $\{N,M,L\}$ such that $N\geq M\geq L\geq 0$ and $N>0$, how can I generate all tuples $\{n,m,l\}$ such that  $n\geq m\geq l\geq 0$ and such that `FromDigits[{N,M,L},N]` is greater than `FromDigits[{n,m,l},N]`?

I would like to have this returned in a $Q\times 3$ List, where $Q$ is the number of distinct tuples $\{n,m,l\}$.

For example, if $\{N,M,L\}=\{2,1,0\}$, then it would return `{{1,0,0},{1,1,0},{1,1,1},{2,0,0},{2,1,0}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
triplesF = Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, 
       {i, 0, #}, {j, 0, If[i == #, #2, i]}, {k, 0, If[i == #, Min[j, #3], j]}]], 3] &;
```

Examples:

```
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}} *)

triplesF[1, 1, 1]
(* {{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}} *)

triplesF[2, 1, 0]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}*)

triplesF[2, 2, 0]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}*)

triplesF[3, 2, 0]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1},
    {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 0}} *)

triplesF[3, 1, 0]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1},
 {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0}} *)
```

**Update:** Some timing comparisons

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = triplesF[10, 10, 10];]
(* 0.001001 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = c[10, 10, 10];]
(* 0.006004 *)
Complement[res1,  res2]
(* {{0, 0, 0}} *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = triplesF[100, 100, 100];]
(* 0.097286 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = c[100, 100, 100];]
(* 3.400685 *)
Complement[res1,  res2]
(* {{0, 0, 0}} *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = triplesF[200, 100, 100];]
(* 0.660541 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = c[200, 100, 100];]
(* 26.008599 *)
Complement[res1,  res2]
(* {{0, 0, 0}} *)
```

**Update 2:** Faster version using `Join@@Join@@` instead of `Partition[Flatten[...],3]` (thanks: Mr.Wizard)

```
triplesFb = Join @@ Join @@ Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0, #},
       {j, 0, If[i == #, #2, i]}, {k, 0, If[i == #, Min[#3, j], j]}] &;

First[AbsoluteTiming[resb = triplesFb[100, 100, 100];]]
(* 0.073053 *)
First[AbsoluteTiming[res1 = triplesF[100, 100, 100];]]
(* 0.094067 *)

resb == res1
(* True *)

{First[AbsoluteTiming[resb = triplesFb[500, 100, 100];]], Length[resb]}
(* {11.780317,20963651} *)
```

Comment: yes, this is just what i wanted

Comment: @science404, thank you for the accept.

Comment: hi, I just noticed that there is slight bug in this solution... it does not return the correct series for [1,1,1], namely it returns `{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}`, but {1,0,1} is incorrect

Comment: @kguler2 sorry for taking away your 'accept'.  thanks for all the help, indeed it motivated the now 'accepted' solution!

Comment: @science404, i updated with a  fix for the issue.

Comment: @science404 You should look at this again.  Direct generation (this answer) really is superior to overproduction and filtering.  kguler: `Join @@ Table` is much faster than your `Flatten`/`Partition` construct.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `Join@@` was the first thing I tried; it doesn't give a 2d list. `Join@@Join@@Table` works.

Comment: @kguler fair enough, you deserve the prize.  sorry everyone for flipping back and forth.  thanks for the help!

Comment: @kguler thank you for this analysis...have never been good at efficient code...just wanted to correct my incorrect understanding of question. You already had  my +1 :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard agree entirely construction of elements ideal over the filtering cases and kguler timing show how quickly diverges...as always learn a lot

Comment: @ubpdqn, thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Correcting my misunderstanding:

```
c[n_, m_, l_] := 
 With[{t = Sort@Tuples[Range[0, n], 3],crit = FromDigits[{n, m, l}, n]},
  Rest@Pick[t,Reverse@Sort[#] == # && FromDigits[#, n] <= crit & /@ t]]
```

So using kguler test cases:

```
Grid[{#, c @@ #, Length[c @@ #]} & /@ {{2, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 1, 
    0}, {3, 2, 0}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Original answer**

```
func[n_, m_, l_] := 
 Rest@With[{tup = Sort@Tuples[{n, m, l}, 3], 
    crit = FromDigits[{n, m, l}, n]}, 
   Pick[tup, 
    Reverse@Sort[#] == # && FromDigits[#, n] <= crit & /@ tup]]
```

I have removed {0,0,0} with `Rest` and ordered in increasing order as per example.

Some testing:

```
Grid[{#, func @@ #} & /@ {{2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2}, {5, 2, 1}},
  Dividers -> {{True, True, {False}, True}, {{True}}}]
```

[image]

As `FromDigits`: $\sum_{j=0}^{\text{Length[d_j]}}d_jb^j$, simply ordering the tuples till element and selecting the elements to the argument and select the elements are non-decreasing yields the same results without needing `FromDigits`:

```
g[n_, m_, l_] := Module[{t = Sort@Tuples[{n, m, l}, 3], p},
  p = t[[;; Position[t, {n, m, l}][[1, 1]]]];
  Rest@Pick[p, Reverse@Sort[#] == # & /@ p]
  ]
```

Comment: hi this isn't quite what I was looking for, but thanks for putting in your time!

Comment: @science404 now I understand from kgulers answer

Comment: @science404 I have, I hope, corrected my answer.

Comment: great thx for this alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
func[n_,m_,l_]:=
  Cases[
   Tuples[{n, m, l}, 3],
   {x_, y_, z_} /; 
    x >= y >= z && FromDigits[{n, m, l}, n] >= FromDigits[{x, y, z}, n]
  ]

func[2,1,0]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: hey, thanks but this one seems to work for that example.